# Incorrect output dictionary from user's input

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary, graph

I need output to be in the form

```
{0: {1:11,2:13}, 1: {0:11,3:14}}
```

But it comes out to

```
{0: {1:['11'],2:['13']}, 1: {0:['11'],3:['14']}}
```

using this

```
graph = {}
N,w = map(int,raw_input().split())
# print N, w
for x in range(0,C):
    i,j,c = raw_input().split()
    graph.setdefault(int(i), {}).setdefault(int(j),[]).append(w)
print graph
```

on INPUT

1st line: Ignore `N=4`, while `C=4` is the number of lines.
2nd line: `i`,`j` are vertices, `w` is the edge weight.

```
4 4
0 1 11
0 2 13
1 0 11
1 3 14
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting lists as values inside your nested dictionary in the following line -

```
graph.setdefault(int(i), {}).setdefault(int(j),[]).append(w)
```

This is why you are getting values inside list, if you are 100% sure that the key:value pairs inside the nested dictionary would always be unique, then you can simply set the value to the key. Example -

```
graph.setdefault(int(i), {})[int(j)] = w
```